# Counting special characters in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Looking for a SQL query in ORACLE that returns the count of all the special characters used in a particular column. Suppose in a column there are 5 rows and each uses two special characters. I am looking for some query that gives 10 as the result.

What I used is:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(Employees, '[^]^A-Z^a-z^0-9^[^.^{^}^ ]' );
```

but it seems to not be working.
Tried a lot over the net but no luck.

Update: looking for a solution with 10g

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you

```
with t as 
(
select 'ar{un' name from dual
union
select 'a#;>' from dual
)

select sum(regexp_count(name,'[^[:alnum:]]')) from t;
```

For 10g we can use this, since regexp_count() is not available in earlier versions

```
with t as 
(
select 'ar{un' name from dual
union 
select 'a;<#' from dual

)
select count(distinct regexp_substr(name,'[^[:alnum:]]',level,1)) from t
connect by level <= LENGTH(regexp_replace(name,'[[:alnum:]]')) + 1;
```

Another approach in 10g as Peach suggested

```
with t as 
(
select 'ar{}n' name from dual union
select 'a;<#'  from dual

)
select  sum(length(regexp_replace(name,'[[:alnum:]]'))) from t;
```

Comment: Oracle introduced REGEXP_COUNT() in 11g, so this solution won't work in earlier versions, but it is undoubtedly the most elegant approach.

Comment: @APC - Yeah sure. Actually am trying now another solution to work in the earlier versions, will update the answer in few minutes

Comment: @Saurabh - Since regexp_count is supported in oracle 11g, you can use this function to count the special characters in each row and you can sum it up with the aggregate function. And also you dont need to complicate your regexp like what you did in your query instead you can use [^[:alnum:]] (! of alphabets and digits) which will give you nothing but special chars

Comment: @arunb2w since I dont have deep knowledge of Oracle, I would highly appreciate if you could please provide an explanation along..

Comment: @arunb2w: I am sorry to say but I dont have 11g .I am with 10 g

Comment: @Saurabh - Updated the answer. Please try this

Comment: No need for hierarchical query. Use regexp_replace to remove alnum characters, find the length and sum it up.

Comment: @ arunb2w...  thanks a ton bud for ur quick rply..but also I wud like a bit explanation of terms used in ur query so that I can fit it with my table and also I could understand a bit more for future use...Plss

Comment: @EAT A Peach : Sorry but I didnt get what you mean by remove alnum characters. How can I edit my database to change some strings of name

Comment: @EatÅPeach - Yes that is very easy one to achieve the result. Thank you. Updated your approach in the answer

Comment: The two approaches shared by you guys are returning two different result.